# Unable to create JOB in SQOOP

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I ran below snippet in SQOOP and ended up with error listed below the code.

**bin/sqoop job --create myjob import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test -username root -password root --table patient  -m 1 --target-dir /Sqoop/MRJob**

> administrator@ubuntu:~/sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-1.0.0$ bin/sqoop job
>   --create myjob import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test -username root -password root --table patient  -m 1 --target-dir /Sqoop/MRJob
>   Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
>   Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
>   Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
>
> 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments
>   for job: 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized
>   argument: import 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool:
>   Unrecognized argument: --connect 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR
>   tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
>   14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument:
>   -username 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: root 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool:
>   Unrecognized argument: -password 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR
>   tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: root 14/07/16 23:23:36
>   ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table 14/07/16
>   23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: patient
>   14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m
>   14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 1
>   14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument:
>   --target-dir 14/07/16 23:23:36 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /Sqoop/MRJob
>
> Try --help for usage instructions. usage: sqoop job [GENERIC-ARGS]
>   [JOB-ARGS] [-- [] [TOOL-ARGS]]
>
> Job management arguments:    --create             Create a new
>   saved job    --delete             Delete a saved job    --exec
>                 Run a saved job    --help
>   Print usage instructions    --list                       List saved
>   jobs    --meta-connect     Specify JDBC connect string for
>   the
>                                   metastore    --show               Show the parameters for a saved job    --verbose
>   Print more information while working
>
> Generic Hadoop command-line arguments: (must preceed any tool-specific
>   arguments) Generic options supported are
>   -conf      specify an application configuration file
>   -D             use value for given property
>   -fs       specify a namenode
>   -jt     specify a job tracker
>   -files     specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
>   -libjars     specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
>   -archives     specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.
>
> The general command line syntax is bin/hadoop command [genericOptions]
>   [commandOptions]

Could some one help me on this??

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Note: My SQL related dictionaries are perfect.
Regards

Comment: something trivial, it is SQOOP and not SCOOP :-).

Answer (score 12):

There is a small change that you need to make in your sqoop command. The right syntax would be

`bin/sqoop job --create myjob -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password root --table PATIENT -m 1 --target-dir /Sqoop/MRJob`

[ Note: "--" and a space before the import. Secondly, use POSIX notation "--" before username and password. Thirdly use upper case to specify table name ] it should work.

Few standards: use **Options file** to store credentials (user name, password and connect string) and pass it as as a parameter to  **--options-file**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write below command.

```
gopal@ubuntu:~$ `sqoop job --create JobName -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/DatabaseName --table tablename -m1 --target-dir /OutPutDirectoryName;`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to set SQOOP_PATH in .bashrc and run

```
user@hostname:~$ gedit .bashrc
```

add following lines in .bashrc file

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
```

Now, you can run sqoop job by

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password root --table patient --m 1 --target-dir /Sqoop/MRJob
```

Comment: have you tried:
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password root --table patient --m 1 --target-dir /Sqoop/MRJob

Comment: @Bala, are you still facing issues ?

Comment: Prithvi - Now the prob is solved. We have to give space between -- and import lik
-- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test

Comment: @Bala Ya, venBigData mentioned it in his answer.